SwiftUI Speak function using AVSpeechSynthesizer is not working
I am using AVSpeechSynthesizer to speak some message in SwiftUI. Below is my View:
let speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack {
                displayImage()
                Spacer()
                displayClassifyingOrError()
                if !isClassifying {
                    displayClassifiedItems()
                        .onAppear(){
                            for item in classifier.classifiedItems {
                                let message = "\(item.item) should go to \(item.bin)"
                                print("Speaking message: \(message)")
                                speak(message)
                            }
                                    
                                
                            
                        }
                }
                
                Spacer()
                backButton()
            }
            .onAppear {
                classifyImage()
                checkESP32Connection()
                speak("test message")
            }

            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }

func speak(_ text: String) {
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
        utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
        speechSynthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }

The problem is that the app is speaking the "test message" and also it is printing the correct message to be spoken (example: item x should go to y bin), but not speaking the message. I have tries adding delay but then also it is not working. Any idea what is going wrong?

I haven't tried, but can you try changing it to @State private var speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer() and see if it works?

Oh my God! It worked! But, why?

If you hold the object as let, whenever the view is redrawn (which happens frequently when states change), the object is re-instantiated, thus its state is reset which means you lose the utterance. To extend the lifespan of an object beyond view redraws, either hold it as a @State, or wrap it in a @StateObject. (singleton or global variable are not recommended for preserving object's lifespan despite they also work) In your case, holding the speech synthesizer with @State is the right way to go.
